# how to make models for user auth(use abstract user) for login and signup using django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

how to make models for user auth(use abstract user) for login and signup using Django?

I want to make login OTP based for ecommerse website.

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    emailId = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I tr above code.
What should I have to add above?

Comment: Follow the link once, this may helpful https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractbaseuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `AbstractUser` if you want to inherit permissions settings and all functions that Django uses.

In settings, you should also add `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "your_module_name.User"`

Answer (score 1):

In Django, making a user model by yourself is not recommended because other 3rd party packages depend on the user models Django provided.

There are two ways you can follow.

[Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

[Using a custom user model when starting a project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)